# Fill area under curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I would like do highlight an area under a plot of data. The first area should be below the plot and above 8 on the y axis. The second area should be below the curve and below the first area and above 6 on the y axis.

Here a sketch and minimal working example (sorry for my poor drawing skills ;) ):

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, pgfplots.fillbetween}

\begin{filecontents}{coordinates.dat}
1 2
2 4
3 5
4 5
5 7
6 9
7 10
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[name path=data] table {coordinates.dat};

\path [name path=p8] (0,8) -- (7,8);
\path [name intersections={of=p8 and data, by=m}];
\draw [name path=p80, dashed] (m) -- (7,8);
%\tikzfillbetween[of=p80 and data]{blue, opacity=0.1};

\path [name path=p6] (0,6) -- (7,6);
\path [name intersections={of=p6 and data, by=m}];
\draw [name path=p60, dashed] (m) -- (7,6);
%\tikzfillbetween[of=p60 and data]{red, opacity=0.1};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I do that?

Maybe tikzfill (see code) is the right way but I don't know how to limit the x and y axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of the option `intersection segments` (see chapter 5.7 "Fill between" in the PGFplots manual):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{filecontents}{coordinates.dat}
1 2
2 4
3 5
4 5
5 7
6 9
7 10
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[name path=data] table {coordinates.dat};

\path [name path=p8] (0,8) -- (7,8);
\path [name intersections={of=p8 and data, by=m}];
\draw [name path=p80, dashed] (m) -- (7,8);

\fill [blue, opacity=0.1, intersection segments={of=data and p8, 
    sequence={L2 -- R2[reverse]}}] -- cycle;

\path [name path=p6] (0,6) -- (7,6);
\path [name intersections={of=p6 and data, by=m}];
\draw [name path=p60, dashed] (m) -- (7,6);

\path [name path=p68, intersection segments={of=data and p6, 
    sequence={L2 -- R2[reverse]}}] -- cycle;

\fill [red, opacity=0.1, intersection segments={of=p68 and p80, 
    sequence={L1 -- L3}}] -- cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I have a hard time to understand the intersection segments sequence. How does that work? Maybe you have a reference in the manual?

Comment: You can go to CTAN (ctan.org) where you can find the [manual for PGFplots](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). The `fillbetween` library is described in chapter 5.7.

Comment: The logic of the syntax is like roughly this: you fed this function two paths, the first one is refered to as `L` (for "left", or as `A`), the second is refered to as `R` (for "right", or as `B`). Both path start somewhere (for closed paths, it is often not very clear where the start is, so one has to try a bit). `L1` now means the first part of the first path, which would be upto the point where this path intersects with the other path. `R2` would mean the second part of the second path, which would be from the first intersection upto the second intersection with the other path.

Answer (score 3):

```
\begin{filecontents}{coordinates.dat}
1 2
2 4
3 5
4 5
5 7
6 9
7 10
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\begin{scope}
\clip plot file {coordinates.dat} |- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=red!40, dashed] (0,6-|current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east);
\filldraw[fill=blue!40, dashed] (0,8-|current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east);
\end{scope}
\addplot+[thick] table {coordinates.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with segment curve and two filled areas]

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful solution. However, I plot the data from a CSV file and`\clip plot table [x=index, y=col2, col sep=comma] {data.csv} |- cycle;` obviously does not work. How would I do that?

Comment: Can I reuse the path from `\addplot` somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can give the option `save path=\pathA` to the plot, and then use `\clip[use path=\pathA];`. Still no extra packages are needed